# Can't use Service Reference after VS 2012 upgrade

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio-2012

**What's happening:**

We have a thick client application that accesses a WCF service that was fully functional before VS2012 was installed. After updating the service reference, it will get errors at compile time. Communicating with service is fine.

**What I've done (at least what I remember trying):**

I've done so many things I probably can't list them all here.

In no particular order:

- Compiled the service, used batch file to copy files to location. (Same batch used before 2012.)
- Ran IISReset
- Removed service reference from client solution, cleaned, closed VS2010, and then added service reference.

**Error:**

Right now in console test application, I'm getting errors about not finding .Net Framework classes:

```
- <pre>Error    1   'System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments   C:\_path_\ServiceReferenceTest2010\ServiceReferenceTest2010\Service References\MyService\Reference.cs   2971    26  ServiceReferenceTest2010

- Error 2   The type or namespace name 'Claims' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\_path_\ServiceReferenceTest2010\ServiceReferenceTest2010\Service References\MyService\Reference.cs   17076   77  ServiceReferenceTest2010

- Error 3   The type or namespace name 'Claims' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\_path_\ServiceReferenceTest2010\ServiceReferenceTest2010\Service References\MyService\Reference.cs   20253   79  ServiceReferenceTest2010

- Error 4   The type or namespace name 'Claims' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\_path_\ServiceReferenceTest2010\ServiceReferenceTest2010\Service References\MyService\Reference.cs   20618   79  ServiceReferenceTest2010

- Error 5   The type or namespace name 'Claims' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\_path_\ServiceReferenceTest2010\ServiceReferenceTest2010\Service References\MyService\Reference.cs   21048   79  ServiceReferenceTest2010
```

**Notes:**

- I'm not an expert in WCF
- The `.datasource` files did not always populate under "Reference.svcmap". I would have to remove and re-add the service reference to get it back multiple times
- I have removed VS2012, uninstalled VS2010, and reinstalled VS2010 + SP1 (No VS2012 installed currently.)
- Checked and Unchecked "Reuse Type", when I unchecked it, it says it can't find my interface.
- Tried unchecking reuse all types and only choosing our namespaces, didn't work
- When I load an older version of our software in a whole different branch, everything is fine if I don't do an update of the service reference
- I've rolled back, from TFS, to way before I installed 2012 and same issue.

Comment: Are you on the same .Net version in service and client? looking at the MSDN documentation for `GenericIdentity` , there is a new construcutor added in 4.5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericidentity(v=vs.110).aspx
This could be the cause

Comment: I've checked before and I made sure to check again. Yep. Using .NET 4.0 on all projects. I've even search though all .csproj files using ctl-shift+F for "TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5" in the entire folder tree and nothing came up.

Comment: Update:

It's a two part issue:

- Had a custom enum variable called "Level" that WCF didn't like.
- With the above fixed (wasn't working on manager's 2010 either) I still can't update the service on my VS 2012.

When I try to get to a ?wsdl? page, I get a warning on the bottom of the page that says "Only secure Content is displayed." with a button "Show all content". I will try to fix this.

Comment: @MarcWeintraub - VS2012 most likely installed .NET 4.5 on your machine. That is not super highly compatible with .NET 4.0 like Microsoft says, tends to brake more things than it fixes... Now I'm not sure how reinstalling VS2010 is going to handle this, but can you make sure that .NET 4.5 is uninstalled? (Start -> Control Panel -> Uninstall programs) .NET 4.0 and 4.5 cannot live side by side, 4.5 will do an inplace upgrade.